# PDF missing border

Tags: tables, overleaf, border

I have a table which look like this on overleaf editor. [image]

When I download the file as a pdf I get something like this, where borders are missing.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
 {\rowcolors{2}{cyan!10}{white}
\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{ |s| p{0.7cm} |p{2cm} |p{0.7cm}| p{2cm} |p{2cm} |p{0.8cm} |p{2.1cm} |p{0.8cm} |p{0.8cm} |p{0.8cm} |p{0.8cm} |p{1cm}| p{1cm}| }


\hline
\rowcolor{azure} \multicolumn{13}{|c|}{Student 1} \\
\hline

{\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont  Exercise1} & {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise2} & {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise3 }& {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise4} & {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise5 } & {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise6} &{\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise7 }&{\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise8 } &{\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise9} & {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise10 } & {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise11} & {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise12} & {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont Exercise13} \\

\hline
1& 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 2 & 83 & -2.5 & -0.1 & -0.4 & 1 & 7  \\
2& 1 & 179 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 21 & -2.5 & -0.1 & -0.4 & 1 & 7 \\
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
221& 7 & 101 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 4 & 103 & -2.5 & -0.1 & -0.4 & 1 & 7 \\
222& 5 & 78 & 1 &  47 & 50 & 0 & 0 & -2.5 & -0.1 & -0.4 & 1 & 7 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Extended Raw Data Table for one student}
\label{Extended_data}
\end{table}
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a full MWE? Also, you probably shouldn't use `\resizebox` with tables. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if this is just a PDF viewer glitch: try zooming in. If using Adobe Reader, look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F28171_01/TSG/FAQ/Fixing%20the%20thin%20line%20display%20issue%20when%20viewing%20a%20PDF.html). Anyway, it's impossible to test your code without the preamble, color and column definitions.

Comment: @frabjous as you said it is just a glitch. thanks alot.

Comment: One (more) reason to never ever use vertical rules in tables. And also o one (more) reason to not use `\resizebox` in tables.

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic:

A bit better look of your table you will obtain with the following code changes:

- remove `\resizebox`
- define equal columns width
- use `array` in math environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\rowcolors{2}{cyan!10}{white}
$
\begin{array}{ |c| *{13}{w{c}{2em}|} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{DodgerBlue} 
\multicolumn{13}{|c|}{\text{Student 1}} \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{13}{|c|}{\text{Exercises}}  \\
    \hline
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 
            & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11  & 12 & 13       \\
    \hline
1   & 0 & 0   & 0 &  0 & 0 & 2 & 83 & -2.5 & -0.1 & -0.4 & 1 & 7    \\
2   & 1 & 179 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 21 & -2.5 & -0.1 & -0.4 & 1 & 7    \\
\vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
221& 7 & 101 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 4 & 103 & -2.5 & -0.1 & -0.4 & 1 & 7    \\
222& 5 & 78 & 1 &  47 & 50 & 0 & 0 & -2.5 & -0.1 & -0.4 & 1 & 7     \\
    \hline
\end{array}
$
\caption{Extended Raw Data Table for one student}
\label{Extended_data}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

IN Sumatra pdf viewer table looks as follows:

[image]